# Use script on div loaded by AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I need to load external content in a div. I found a code to do that, but my scripts does not work anymore. Someone can help ? I'm novice in this kind of work.

Thanks

```
function ajaxFunction(id, url){
    var xmlHttp;
    try {// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    } catch (e) {// Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            //Get the response from the server and extract the section that comes in the body section of the second html page avoid inserting the header part of the second page in your first page's element
            var respText = xmlHttp.responseText.split('<body>');
            elem.innerHTML = respText[1].split('</body>')[0];
        }
    }

    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!elem) {
        alert('The element with the passed ID doesn\'t exists in your page');
        return;
    }

    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);

}
```

**EDIT - Here is my HTML code. This is were i call my ajax.**

```
<div id="right" class="anim">
    <div class="exit">
    <a class="btnclose"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio-box" id="git-box"></div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
        <div id="centerContainer" class="col-lg-12">
            <div id="grid">

                <div class="box" data-category="Branding" data-move="right">                    
                    <div class="hide" data-thumbnail="images/portfolio/branding/git.jpg"> </div>
                    <a type="link" value="Call Project" id="project-link" onclick="ajaxFunction('git-box','portfolio/git.html')">
                    <div class="thumbnail-caption">
                        <h3>Groupe<br> intégration<br> Travail</h3>
                        <h5>Branding</h5>
                    </div></a>
                </div>
```

**EDIT - This is the code that must be activated in the div inserted by AJAX**

```
(function () {
    var $frame = $('#centered');
    var $wrap  = $frame.parent();

    // Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
        horizontal: 1,
        itemNav: 'centered',
        smart: 1,
        activateOn: 'click',
        mouseDragging: 1,
        touchDragging: 1,
        releaseSwing: 1,
        startAt: 1,
        scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
        scrollBy: 1,
        speed: 300,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        dragHandle: 1,
        dynamicHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1,

        // Buttons
        prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
        next: $wrap.find('.next')
    });

    $(window).resize(function(e) {

    $frame.sly('reload');
    });

}());

});
```

Comment: You added jQuery label to this question, why don't you use its AJAX methods?

Comment: "The script doesn't work"... You mean you have error in console ?

Comment: I think more information is needed, how are you calling the function, does the div you want to post to exist? Posting the entire page should help.

Comment: Are you talking about scripts in the page you load via Ajax or are you talking about the script in your question?

Comment: My assumption without seeing any other code, is that you're replacing HTML in the body, so if you remove elements and re-add them, any events bound directly to them will no longer fire. You will need to use event delegation for elements that are removed and then re-added to the DOM. jQuery's `.on()` handles those events perfectly.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - It's exactly what Ohgodwhy is talking about. Do you have a concrete exemple ? I'm visual person and novice i need to see how it works to understand. Sorry for my english. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the whole js that you want to apply to the ajax loaded content in a function :

```
function loadSly() {
    var $frame = $('#centered');
    var $wrap  = $frame.parent();

    // Call Sly on frame
    $frame.sly({
        horizontal: 1,
        itemNav: 'centered',
        smart: 1,
        activateOn: 'click',
        mouseDragging: 1,
        touchDragging: 1,
        releaseSwing: 1,
        startAt: 1,
        scrollBar: $wrap.find('.scrollbar'),
        scrollBy: 1,
        speed: 300,
        elasticBounds: 1,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        dragHandle: 1,
        dynamicHandle: 1,
        clickBar: 1,

        // Buttons
        prev: $wrap.find('.prev'),
        next: $wrap.find('.next')
    });

    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        $frame.sly('reload');
    });
}
```

Then execute it after the html insert :

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        //Get the response from the server and extract the section that comes in the body section of the second html page avoid inserting the header part of the second page in your first page's element
        var respText = xmlHttp.responseText.split('<body>');
        elem.innerHTML = respText[1].split('</body>')[0];
        // here you apply the javascript code to the html loaded
        loadSly();
    }
}
```